# PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I created a new Zend framework 1 project (I need to learn ZF1 for a old app I'll be working on) using the following command: `zf create project zf-tutorial`

... but I get an error telling me: `PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created.`

However, I have phpunit installed and I can confirm this by going to the terminal and running `phpunit`

I installed PHPUnit from their homepage - http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/installation.html

I suspect that `zf create *` will generate my test files/folders similar to Rails? I really like this feature and would like to enable it for ZF too (if possible)

Any reason why zend tool isn't picking up phpunit?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the path where the phpunit is located into your include_path in your php.ini file? phpunit may be in your shell PATH but might not be in the include_path...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I run `which phpunit` and it tells me - `/usr/local/bin/phpunit`. So I uncommented the `include_path = ...` in php.ini (I got the php.ini file path by doing `php -i`) and added - `include_path = ".:/usr/share/php;/usr/local/bin"`. I then restarted apache, and generated some actions in Zend tool but it still gives me a phpunit missing message.

Comment: which version of zf1 is it? And in which file/line does the error occur?

Comment: `zf show version` tells me it's v1.12.7. Doesn't occur on any file/ line. It's when I run a Zend tool command e.g. `zf create project myapp` .. then I get the message.

Comment: cool... the test if phpunit is available is in `Zend_Tool_Project_Provider_Test::isPHPUnitAvailable`
(https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/release-1.12.7/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Provider/Test.php from line 58-71

in particular it seems the line `$included = @include 'PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php';` that seems to be responsible for it working or not.... 

what about  if you create an empty php file with just `<?php var_dump(include 'PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php');`-the (error) message(s) might help in determining what's wrong.maybe check the filsystem structure of where phpunit is installed

Comment: Yeh it just tells that `Warning: include(PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/zf-tutorial/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 13 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/zf-tutorial/application/../library:/var/www/zf-tutorial/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/zf-tutorial/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 13 bool(false) `. The directory I added to the include path doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: The Zend tool does run on the command line and uses a different `php.ini` file than the instance running inside Apache. Run `php -i` on the command line and look for the info which `php.ini` file is being used.

Comment: I see. When I run simply `php -i` I gives an overwhelming amount to text. When I run `php -i | grep php.ini` it just tells me `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini` which is the php.ini file for the CLI. Is there some way I can narrow the result down to what I should be looking for?